# How do I read multiple chars and convert in to Ascii?

Tags: c, hex, ascii

I have an input in hex format separated with space: (e.g.) 4A 49 5A
I need to read that line and print the same line but in Ascii format: J I Z
I've actually did the reverse (ascii to hex) but can't adapt it to the needed case.
I can use only `stdio.h` and `string.h`
Below is the code ascii to hex.

```
    char *line = NULL;
    char *token;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;

    read = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    if (read == -1) {
        printf("n/a\n");
        return 0;
    }
      
    while ((token = strsep(&line, " ")) != NULL) {
        printf("%X ", *token);
    }
    return 1;
```

And there are my tries to make hex to ascii work. As I understood, variable `read` also doesn't work correctly in this case.

```
    char *token;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;
    int e;

    read = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    if (read == -1) {
        printf("n/a\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%zd", read);
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(read)/sizeof(char)); i++) {
        e = line[i];
        //printf("%c", line[i]);
        //printf("%d ", e);
    }

    // while ((token = strsep(&line, " ")) != NULL) {
    //     printf("%d", (int)*token);
    //}
    return 1;
```

Comment: FYI: `sizeof char` is always 1 and you should already know that x/1=x. But `sizeof(read)` is the same as `sizeof(ssize_t)` and is not equal to the number of character read by `getline`. `getline` returns the number of characters in a ssize_t value, so just `i < read` should suffice.

Comment: And read is a terrible variable name for what should be readCount or something similar.

Comment: Well, `printf` is fine for the direction you managed to handle already – but that's a one-way street... The street leading back is called `scanf` or in your case [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) respectively, as you've read entire lines already...

Comment: On the otherhand, as you have two character input anyway, doing so by hand is pretty simple: `digits = "0123456789abcdef"; val = strchr(digits, tolower(line[n])) - digits;` (or, if you have guaranteed upper case letters only, capital letters in `digits` and skip calling `tolower`). Then get the values for two subsequent characters and calculate `value = high * 16 + low`.

Comment: My personally preferred variant for handling both upper and lower case: `digits = "0123456789abcdefABCDEF"; val = strchr(digits, line[n]) - digits; val -= (val >15) * 6;`